# Generate series of data with similar average, variance, autocorrelation and "spikyness"

Tags: distributions, standard-deviation, autocorrelation, random-generation, mean

**Context:** I have a couple of series of data, stock index data. I translate those distributions into two input stream for a videogame, and let the input compete. One of the two is definitively more efficient than the other (more than 50% more), and I wanted to prove or disprove that the most efficient series is due to it's *spikyness* (being the winner more *spiky*).  With *spiky* I mean the opposite of *smooth*: I don't know the statistical term for this qualifier, but it probably is affected by the difference between a point and the near points (since a smooth line has no big difference between near values)

**My objective:** Generate a series *similar* (meaning: same average, std deviation, and autocorrelation) to an already existent series, with fixed range [0, 1].

In particular, one of my original series is the following:

[image: Graph 1]

Average: 0,3454

Standard Deviation: 0,1831

Auto-correlation: 0,02306

Bounds: [0,1]

To generate a randomized series that shares these values, these are my steps:

Graph 2
[image: Graph 2]

Graph 3
[image: Graph 3]

1. I generate a linear series with given average. (Purple line, gr 2)
2. I generate, every 50 elements, a random variation from that curve. I vary from a random number between -0,2 and 0,2, that is a completely arbitrary number, chosen by trial and error. (Blue line, gr 2)
3. Same procedure, but every element and with a step of -0,021 and 0,021. (Final result, as shown in the first graph, gr 3)

Average: 0,3572 (Similar enough)

Standard Deviation: 0,2351 (A bit off)

Auto-correlation: 0,02314 (Pretty good)

Bounds: [0, 0,8175] (A bit off)

I am not completely satisfied with the result. The values are there and they are similar enough, but the shapes of the two series are different for my purpose: my generated series seems to change more prominently "point-by-point", and it definitely looks more *spiky*. **Is this the best method to achieve the result? Is autocorrelation a good qualifier for "spikyness"**?

Note on the autocorrelation: I am using Excel for calculation, generation and plotting, and what I calculate is the derivative point by point of the original distribution, and the Standard Deviation of the newly-obtained distribution is the auto-correlation. Is it the right/fastest way to proceed?

Comment: You say that you have a certain "purpose". What is it?

Comment: I added the context to the question.

**Context:** I have a couple of distributions, stock index data. I translate those distributions into two input stream for a videogame, and let the input compete. One of the two is definitively more efficient than the other (more than 50% more), and I wanted to prove or disprove that the most efficient distribution is due to it's *spikyness* (being the winner more *spiky*).

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly what you mean by spiky and jaggy. Is it point to point variation or is it a distribution of feature frequencies that matter? Without a clearer understanding my intuitive answer is to explore either Markov chains (random walks) or Fourier transforms (which can generate features over a distribution of frequencies).

Comment: This question is incomprehensible because the plots are not "distributions" in any standard sense of the word.  I will refund your bounty so you have time to clarify the question; otherwise I'm concerned you will have wasted your reputation for nothing.

Comment: @ReneBt, defining "spiky" is exactly what the question is about. What i mean is that is the opposite of smooth, and i suppose a good qualifier of that takes into account the difference point-by-point. I guessed autocorrelation, but the result is that two series with same autocorrelation are "visibly" different, the second one being a lot less smooth.

Comment: @whuber I changed every instance of "distribution" with "series". But does it really make any difference? if on the y-axis there were frequency instead of value, what would change for the scope of the question?

Comment: the original series has many more elements of randomness than you have coded for. There are occasions that no change occurs, and the variability in how much change occurs appears much larger. Maybe you should explore random walk with a range of input behaviours and analyse the Fourier transform of the output to get a power spectrum that shows a similar distribution of frequencies to your original series. This advice is based on my assuming you are really interested in the distribution of feature frequencies (so the size and shape of undulations at all levels), not just  variance between points